Firebase: Sign In With Google Keeps Logging Out User
I tried utilizing firebase google auth services for an app I'm trying to make:
Here's my code (firebaseUtil.jsx):
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithRedirect,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const firebase = {
     // info goes here
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebase);
export const auth = getAuth();
export const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export const logIn = () => {
  // makes sure the users signs in with a restricted mail.
  googleProvider.setCustomParameters({
    hd: "domain.name",
    prompt: "select_account",
  });

  signInWithRedirect(auth, googleProvider);
};


  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      console.log(user.email);
      navigate("/userPage"); 
    } else {
      console.log("signed-out!");
    }
  });



export const logOut = () => {
  signOut(auth);
};




Whenever I try to sign in, it always consoles signed out in the console console message
However, on my firebase project auth dashboard, the user was logged in.
I tried using onAuthStateChanged however it always says that I am signed out. There was once this instance where I was able to sign-in however after a shortwhile it logged out again and after that i wasn't able to sign in again.
